# Google Docs Chrome extension - what does it do / why does it exist?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-workspace

In some Chrome instances, several extensions (apps?) called Google Docs, Google Sheets, etc. are installed (I've seen various subsets of these across different Chrome instances).  What are these for / what do they do / why do they exist?

I verified that I can go offline and use Drive, Docs, Sheets, etc. just fine with these extensions disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google decided to unbundle several of their Drive apps as separate standalone apps. I can't speak to the 'why', although you can to learn more about this strategy by reading The Next Web's take on [Why large tech companies are hopping on the app ‘unbundling’ trend](http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2014/05/06/large-tech-companies-hopping-app-unbundling-trend/).

I can speak to one benefit of this app unbundling. Windows, Chrome OS and Linux users are able to take advantage of a Google Chrome (Chromium) feature that allows them to [create shortcuts to apps](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en).

A Chrome app shortcut essentially gives the web app a standalone desktop application feel. Your work doesn't necessarily get lost in the many open tabs you may have open in your browser, and you have more screen real estate to work with because the omnibar and tabs are absent.

[image: Stand Alone Desktop Web Apps]

This lends itself nicely to switching between open applications using keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image: Alt Tab on Ubuntu]

I've grown accustomed to this approach and like it. But you're right, at this point you can comfortably disable these apps and use Drive for productivity and file storage just fine.